# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: roboguice.activity.SherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity with ActiveAndroid in android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, roboguice, activeandroid

I am getting this error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: roboguice.activity.SherlockAccountAuthenticatorActivity
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152)
at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63)
at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:30)
at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:25)
at com.dvor.androidapp.Application.TabletApplication.onCreate(TabletApplication.java:22)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1011)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4518)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1339)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

In Android version 5.0, I am using RoboGuice and ActiveAndroid and the application class is extending com.activeandroid.app.Application, is there any other way how to fix this issue except extending the normal Application class and adding the model classes manually(this way it each model class needs to be added), as explained(https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/291) :

```
  Configuration.Builder configurationBuilder = new Configuration.Builder(this);
    configurationBuilder.addModelClass(Test.class);
    configurationBuilder.addModelClass(Test2.class);
    ActiveAndroid.initialize(configurationBuilder.create());
```

Comment: You could try http://www.rushorm.com/ it does not require extending an Application class. Works in a very similar way otherwise.

Comment: @Stuart Campbell Looks interesting but I am unable to change ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround for this problem, was adding the Roboguice jar files, and ActiveAndroid jar files to lib folder, and replacing Gradle "compile" command with -

```
compile files('libs/ActiveAndroid.jar')
compile files('libs/simple.facebook-2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/roboguice-3.0b-experimental.jar')
```